# Why a position absolute element's scroll bar is influenced by position fixed element in chrome?

Tags: html, css

Today I came across a frustrated problem. The scroll bar of a position absolute element would be positioned differently when there is a position fixed element underneath,  as shown in the gray div 
[image: The scroll bar is position incorrectly, there is a margin at the right hand side]

then I tried to reduce the height of the fixed div, and the scroll bar is back to nromal[image]

Besides, when I set the body to overflow hidden, the child's scroll bar is normal as well regardless of the height of the fixed div. This situation only happens in Chrome, while the scroll bar in the Safari is fine

Some css for these two divs:

```
#popup-div {
  cursor: default;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  width: 360px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px #E2E2E2;
  right: -83px;
  z-index: 99;
}


.side-div {
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: -10px 1px 10px #EAEAEA;
  height: 32%;
  min-width: 222px;
  width: 17%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 96;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Any explanation about this?

Comment: maybe try "clear:both;" on your underneath element? Can you make a fiddle of this? this would be easier to see what's exactly going on... http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Julo0sS, it still doesn't work

Comment: jsfiddle would helppppppp.... :P

Comment: I was trying to make one, and use a simplified version, and it works. But the real code is more complicated@Julo0sS

Comment: find out what's going wrong in your "complicated" version then... ^^

Comment: problem is probably in your "full css"...